# Create BufferedImage from YBR_FULL Dicom Image

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I want to Create BufferedImage from YBR_FULL Dicom Image to view it over a JPanel in my program, can any one tell me how to deal with this type of Dicom file?also can we convert from YBR_FULL to RGB? if yes how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert the YBR values to RGB.  here's a page on [how to convert between YBR and RGB](http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php)

Comment: what is the steps to use these formulas ?
i should read the image in ByteBuffer and deals with byte pixel values in these formulas ?

Comment: i use these formulas but i got an image contains columns of separated colors (Red, green, and blue).

Comment: sounds like you have byte alignment wrong.  YBR stores a pixel using 3 bytes.  if using RGB, you'll need to store 3 bytes into your buffer.  if using RGBA, you'll need to store 4 bytes

Answer (score 0):

The formula that worked for me was this:

```
R = Y + 1.402 * (Cr-128);
G = Y - 0.344136 * (Cb-128) - 0.714136 * (Cr-128);
B = Y + 1.772 * (Cb-128);
```

I found it [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.compression/c/q6svVG4hie0/m/cL4SvBilsHcJ).