# Conversion from YBR_FULL to RGB in c++?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, rgb, dicom

Could you please explain the relationship between YBR_FULL and RGB so that I'm able to convert the YBR_FULL image to RGB in C++?

I'm getting the pixel data from a Dicom image as bytes in a buffer using DCMTK library. For some selected pixels I set the pixel values as 0, for RGB that works fine as when the images are Visualized the pixel values which are set to 0 are shown as black, but in case of YBR_FULL the those pixels are shown as green. I don't quite understand what the problem is. Could you please elaborate what mistake I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

this has been answered

[Create BufferedImage from YBR_FULL Dicom Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873867/create-bufferedimage-from-ybr-full-dicom-image)

here's the link to the mathemetical formula

http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php

Comment: Using these formulas rendering becomes slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the YBR values to (0,0,0) your luminance (Y) is in the correct value, but the chroma (B and R) zero point is exactly in te middle of the range, so you should try with the value 128 (if B and R have one byte size). then you have YBR = (0, 128U, 128U)

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but 128U means 128? Like if `buffer` is the buffer in which the pixel values are stored then to set YBR value to 0, I should do `buffer[index] = 0, buffer[index+1] = 128, buffer[index+2] = 128`?

Comment: 128U means 128 but for considering the byte (or char) unsigned. There are many YBR layouts and types, for example if it is planar, then you have in your buffer all the Y values first, then all the B values and finally all the R values, if is interleaved there are many interleave modes. I will take a look to DCMTK lib to see how is ordered

Comment: I'm dealing with the planar images and I was setting Y = 0, B = 128, R = 128 to make those pixels black. But nothing doing, it keeps showing green. I tried to follow the codes from the following link:
http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/html/gdcmImageChangePhotometricInterpretation_8h_source.html 
Conversion from RGB to YBR works but not the RGB to YBR. I don't know why it doesn't work. My task during the RGB to YBR conversion is to just set some specific pixels as black, but those pixels keep showing green

Comment: Well I had the same issue some time ago, and seeing this image http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:YCbCr-CbCr_Scaled_Y50.png the green color is in the bottom left side, so the zero value is the middle of the scale. In my case it works, I can't understand why don't work in your case. The only thing I can imagine is that there is many planar modes (YBR422, YBR420, and go on) and you could be changing the wrong pixel chroma.